# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function in my code

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have problem with my code, the error is `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function.`

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  description: "Display ping latency.",

  run(msg, args) {
    let waiting = await message.channel.send("Calculation...").catch(console.error)

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

      .setTitle("Bot & Discord.js API latency", bot.user.avatarURL)
      .setColor(0xb348ff)
      .setField("BOT :", "> '" + '${waiting.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}' + "ms'", true)
      .setField("API :", "'" + Math.round(bot.ping) + "ms'", true)
      .setTimestamp(message.createdAt)
      .setTimestamp()

    waiting.edit(embed).catch(console.error)
  }
}
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?

Answer (score -1):

The error says it all, you can only use `await` inside of an asynchronous (`async`) function.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  description: "Display ping latency.",

  async run(msg, args) {
    let waiting = await message.channel.send("Calculation...").catch(console.error)

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

      .setTitle("Bot & Discord.js API latency", bot.user.avatarURL)
      .setColor(0xb348ff)
      .setField("BOT :", "> '" + '${waiting.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}' + "ms'", true)
      .setField("API :", "'" + Math.round(bot.ping) + "ms'", true)
      .setTimestamp(message.createdAt)
      .setTimestamp()

    waiting.edit(embed).catch(console.error)
  }
}
```